# Render radio values using Django BoundField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Hi I want to return form radio values as a JSON from my view. I don't want the html tags, just raw data of radio values.

By writing {{ form.q1.field.choice_label }} in html I can get what I want. But I want to get it in views and pass it as json to html.

This is my views.py code:

```
def FormBotAPI(request):
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()


    for x in form.fields:
        data = {
            'label_str': form[x].label,
            'values': str(form[x]),
        }
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

forms.py:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    types1 = (
        ('destinations', 'to'),
        ('fields', 'questions'),
        ('rankings', 'about'),
        ('Others', 'human'),
    )
    types2 = (
        ('destinations', 'to1'),
        ('fields', 'questions1'),
        ('rankings', 'about1'),
        ('Others', 'human1'),
    )
    q1 = models.CharField (
        'fieldlabel',
        help_text='helptext',
        max_length=200,
        choices=types1, blank=False, null=True, default='Unspecified'
    )
    q2 = models.CharField (
        'fieldlabel',
        help_text='helptext',
        max_length=200,
        choices=types2, blank=False, null=True, default='zz'
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do it. I did a research and didn't find any shortcut.

Simply, I returned the values by stripping HTML tag. I used strip-tags shortcut from Django itself.

*My views.py:*

```
import requests
from .models import *
from django.http import JsonResponse  
from django.utils.html import strip_tags



def FormBotAPI(request):
    form = UserForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
        

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    field = 'q1'

        # Delete HTML tags
    radio_inputs = [ strip_tags(html_inputs).replace('\n ', '') for html_inputs in form[field] ]
        # return unique id for each input and label
    id_for_label = [ form[field].auto_id + '_' + str(id) for id in range(len(radio_inputs)) ]
        # Make a dictionary from two above
    choices = [ {'id': id_for_label[i], 'label': radio_inputs[i]} for i in range(len(radio_inputs)) ]

            

    data = {
            'label': form[field].label,
            'help_text': form[field].help_text,
            'choices': choices,
    }

    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Added widgets to ModelForm:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, RadioSelect


class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'q1': RadioSelect(),
        }
```